# get error when calling call() in Python

Tags: python, call, traceback

I'm using python to run an external program as follows

```
 call("/usr/sbin/snif")
```

and I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 480, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I get the last line, that says :

"No such file or directory"

or better yet, how do I know if the execution succeeded or not?

Thanks

Comment: `snif` isn't a Python script, is it? Also, are you sure it's `snif` and not `sniff`?

Comment: it's not...it doesn't exist..I just wanted to see how I can get the error

Comment: The question is not why Im getting the error, but how I can get the last line..or get a -1 flag if it fails or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the error:

```
try:
    call('/usr/sbin/snif')
except OSError:
    print "It didn't execute"
```

If you want to see if the command executed correctly, use `check_output` or `check_call` instead and catch another error:

```
import subprocess:

try:
    subprocess.check_output('/usr/sbin/snif')
except OSError:
    print 'That file does not exist'
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print 'Bad exit code'
```

Comment: " 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output' "

Comment: @user1432779: That function doesn't exist in Python 2.6. You can use [this code](https://gist.github.com/1027906) as a hack to include it.